# Terraform does not match any of the checksums recorded in the dependency lock file

Tags: terraform

We want to use https://www.terraform.io/language/files/dependency-lock instead of having "version" lines like `version = "~> 4.16.0"` & `required_version = "~> 1.2.1"` littering our Terraform `init.tf` files.

However we ran into this **terraform does not match any of the checksums recorded in the dependency lock file** issue & it appears because the [lock file is platform dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67204812).

To work around this issue we now have a Makefile target that looks like:

```
init:
    terraform init

providers-lock: # linux_amd64 is for Gitlab
    terraform providers lock -platform=linux_amd64

plan: init providers-lock
    terraform plan -out tfplan
```

It would appear that init target downloads ~400M of Terraform AWS dependencies, and then providers-lock then fixes the checksum. Is this the best workaround for developers who commit from darwin, for infrastructure as code that is deployed via Linux?

It's not clear whether `terraform providers lock -platform=linux_amd64` downloads another ~400M after the init!

Comment: What is the size if you do init locally? It sounds about right.

Comment: Init locally is 400M, tbh we don't know what it is in the Gitlab CI/CD

Comment: Ok, but can you elaborate a bit what is the question? But yes, the short answer is that you need to download the files for the CPU architecture you are using.

Comment: Assuming .terraform.lock.hcl is for darwin, would that mean my pipeline has to download linux deps from an init? Isn't that rather inefficient?

Comment: Well, if it's a binary compiled for a different CPU (e.g., Darwin vs Linux) I would say there is no other option. :)

Comment: Perhaps I could somehow have a hook that only commit .terraform.lock.hcl for linux?

Comment: If you specify providers well in your configs and modules, and responsibly manage dependencies, then you do not need the `.terraform.lock.hcl` at all. It exists to avoid those efforts.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Are you suggesting I don't use a terraform lock file? Sorry I gravitated towards a lock file to pin my dependencies due to my past favourable experiences with nodejs/gomod, so I am surprised with Terraform's implementation!

Comment: @hendry Yes it is analogous to lock files in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Under Terraform CLI's default configuration, `terraform init` will write into the lock file all of the checksums that were signed by the provider developer and published into the origin registry. In that case, as long as the provider developer provided signatures for all of the available packages the lock file will be sufficient to work across all of that provider's supported platforms.

Things get more tricky if you [reconfigure Terraform CLI's provider installation behavior](https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file#provider-installation), because only the true origin registry (typically `registry.terraform.io`, for most providers) can vouch for the provider developer's public key and thus help Terraform CLI to prove that all of the official checksums are correct without downloading them and calculating the checksums locally.

In particular, all of the following will cause `terraform init` to conservatively record only the exact package it installed:

- Setting `plugin_cache_dir` to make Terraform cache packages locally. When you install a provider that isn't already in the cache Terraform will install it in the usual way and may generate a full complement of checksums (unless one of the remaining points is also true), but if Terraform installs from the cache then it can only calculate the checksum of the package that's already in the cache.
- Configuring `filesystem_mirror` or `network_mirror` for some or all providers tells Terraform it should use a local, non-authoritative source for installing those providers. In that case, Terraform will not contact the origin registry at all and so it cannot obtain checksums for anything except the exact package it installed.
- If you place providers in [the implied local mirror directories](https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file#implied-local-mirror-directories) without explicitly configuring any `provider_installation` block then Terraform will generate an implied `provider_installation` block as described in the docs, which will prevent Terraform from accessing the origin registry for any providers that are in those directories.

For best results, I'd recommend using only the default settings in the development environment where you are writing and testing your modules. Your development environment can then generate a lock file with a full complement of signed checksums which you can place in your version control.

If you use settings which prevent Terraform from accessing the origin registry in any case then the `terraform providers lock` command is there to help you generate checksums from packages that Terraform would not otherwise have any reason to download. In order to achieve that it must typically download those packages, because it's impossible for Terraform to calculate a checksum for a package it doesn't have access to.

Using only the default provider installation settings is the easiest path and I would recommend that for most situations, but `terraform providers lock` is there for those who choose to use non-default provider installation settings.